# Get JSON from NSURLSession with IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsurlsession

I'm building my app with TheMovieDB API but my JSONObject always is nil.I don't know what I'm doing wrong.This is my code:

```
@implementation SKTMovieLibrary

-(id) init{

   if (self = [super init]) {


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=myApiKey"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *err){


        NSDictionary * movieDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


        NSArray *JSONArray =  [movieDict objectForKey:@"results"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            _JSONObject = JSONArray;

        });


    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you look at your data argument in the debugger? does your dataTask return any results?

Comment: No,nothing and I have set a breakpoint in the completion block and it is working correctly but when it finish the JSONObject is nil again.

Comment: not sure I understood you. So in your completion handler for task, the data is nil or not? If it is not nil, your jsonArray has content, right? and then when you do dispatch jsonObject is nil?

Comment: also... _JSONObject looks like a strong property, shouldn't it have self. JSONObject since it's inside a block, and maybe use weak, to make sure you don't have retain cycle ?

Comment: In my completion block, the data is not nil and my jsonArray has content but when i do dispatch jsonObject is nil and i need it for do a for in and create my model for each NSDictionary in jsonObject

Comment: @property (weak,nonatomic) NSArray *jsonObject;

Comment: JSONArray inside of the dispatch block, is it nil? Have you tried to allocate array ? NSArray *JSONArray =  [NSArray arrayWithArray:[movieDict objectForKey:@"results"]]; ?

Comment: No JSONArray isnt nil inside of the dispatch block

Comment: I just ran your code, and it works, BUT...for me it's not in the init method...can this be an issue?

Comment: In what method did u do it?I'm going to try it

Comment: for me it's a viewController, so I placed it in viewWillAppear

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin yes but in my case i have it in a model of a list of movie object for a collection view controller so i must do in my model

Comment: hm...you're trying to get the UI items from the cloud, right? like images and stuff....you should do this in the viewController...where your collectionView is...on viewWillAppear do this request...give a spinner...then load your view, I don't think you should do the data fetch in the model!

Comment: On my last application I did a similar model with wines and it works fine  but i don't know why it doesn't work now

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [_session dataTaskWithURL:url
 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, 
NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
  photo.thumbNail = image;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    cell.thumbnailImage.image = photo.thumbNail;
  });
} else {
  // HANDLE ERROR //
}
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: I have tried the same code but in CollectionViewController in viewWillAppears and i have the same issue

Comment: and your @property (weak,nonatomic) NSArray *jsonObject; is a property inside CollectionViewController ? Can you please post that code? top of your class with properties declared and down to init methods like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc. ?